# Is there another alternative to break?

Tags: c++

I have problems with the break instruction;

Indeed, in my case I reproduce below an example of my calculation code, I work with two nested for loops and if loops.

I would like when the open_bound variable = 0, to completely exit the loops and thus display the value of time t. After execution I see the display of time t = 0 instead of 3 and I have trouble understanding why. Can you please enlighten me?

Is there another alternative to break? (I can't use goto, moreover I parallelize this part in the real code)

Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
      
int main () {
    int numtracers = 1000;
    int save_t;
    double t;
     
    int open_bound = 0;
    int tau = 5;
    double int_step = 0.25;
     
    for (int i = 0; i < numtracers; i++) {
        // Variable to overwrite the successive positions of each particle
        vector <double> coord(2);
        coord[0] = 0.1;
        coord[1] = 0.2;
        int result_checkin;
        for(t=0; t<tau-1; t+=int_step) {
            save_t = t;
            // Function to check if coordinates are inside the domain well defined
            // result_checkin = check_out(coord);
            if (t == tau-2) result_checkin = 1;
            if (result_checkin == 1) { // Particle goes outside domain
                if (open_bound == 0) {  
                    break;                         
                }
                else {
                    coord[0]+=0.1;
                    coord[1]+=0.1;                     
                }
            }
            else {
                coord[0]+=0.1;
                coord[1]+=0.1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << save_t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One way would be to move the code to a function, and return when `(open_bound == 0)`

Comment: After the closing brace of the inner loop, just add: `if (open_bound == 0) break;`

Comment: @Adrian can you explicit please there are so many inner loop

Comment: @xEric_xD maybe not a good idea because after the loops i need to write time & coordinates in a file

Comment: @Adrian, unfortunately i get the same result, 0

Comment: Problem may be that, as far as I can see, you are never setting the value of `open_bound` to zero!

Comment: @MadiopLO There's multiple ways to return data from a function, you can pass arguments by reference, or store the coordinates and time variables in a struct and change the return type of the function.

Comment: @Adrian i set open_bound in the code but i already have the same result, 0 instead of 3

Comment: @xEric_xD exact Eric, i just want to understand why i doesn't print 3

Comment: When a `break` occurs within nested loops, it only breaks out of the inner most loop.   If you want it to back out of all your nested loops, you need to make that happen deliberately (e.g.  `if (condition) break;` in the inner loop, and another `if (condition) break;` immediately after the inner loop body).     While a `goto` can break out of nested loops, it is considered bad practice for many good and bad reasons.

Comment: Your outer loop doesn't use `i` so the whole loop seems useless,

Comment: @Jarod42 it used after to write coordinates and time of tracers in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to exit all loops you want is to use a bool flag in order to decide when to force the loops to terminate. When you hit `open_bound=0` you can first set the flag to false and then break.

Check the following to have an idea about what I mean:

```
 bool go = true;
 for (int i = 0; go &&  CONDITION1; i++)
      for (int j = 0; go &&  CONDITION2; j++)
               for (int k = 0; go &&  CONDITION3; k++)
                     ....
                    if(open_bound==0){
                       go = false;
                       break;
                    }
```

A working version off your code is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lwwlFp4kCIeCQKrT)

Comment: I get the same result with open_bound = 1, the problem occur when opend_bound = 0

Comment: @MadiopLO I have update the answer with your code fixed.

Comment: @Davide, i get the same result, i think you test with open_bound = 1

Comment: @MadiopLO check the link. open_bound is set to zero

Comment: sorry @DavideSpataro it perfect it give me the good result, you just forget to exit the outer loop with the command included by Adrian

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's first recap on what the `break` statement does (not counting its use in a `switch` block): it 'breaks' out of the innermost enclosing `for`, `while` or `do ... while` loop. Thus, `if` statements aren't considered here - and they aren't really ***loops***, are they.

So, in your main code, you only really have **two** loops. Your own `break` will exit the innermost, jumping *immediately* to the point I've highlighted in the code below. Adding the extra `if ... break;` code, as I have done, will exit the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numtracers; i++) {
    int open_bound = 0; // MUST HAVE HERE to parallelize this loop!
    // Variable to overwrite the successive positions of each particle
    vector <double> coord(2);
    coord[0] = 0.1;
    coord[1] = 0.2;
    int result_checkin;
    for(t=0; t<tau-1; t+=int_step) {
        save_t = t;
        // Function to check if coordinates are inside the domain well defined
        // result_checkin = check_out(coord);
        if (t == tau-2) result_checkin = 1;
        if (result_checkin == 1) { // Particle goes outside domain
            if (open_bound == 0) {  
                break; // Exits the inner for loop and goes to the "-->HERE" line!               
            }
            else {
                coord[0]+=0.1;
                coord[1]+=0.1;                     
            }
        }
        else {
            coord[0]+=0.1;
            coord[1]+=0.1;
        }
    }
    // Your "break" exits the for loop and execution continues -->HERE
    if (open_bound == 0) break; // This will (always) exit the outer loop!
}
```

Does this help? Feel free to ask for further explanation!

> EDIT - Note on Loop Parallelisation: If you want to parallelize the
>   *outer* loop, then you will only be able to do so if you move the declaration/definition of `open_bound` inside that outer loop (as I
>   have done in the code above)! You can't parallelize if your are trying
>   to modify and test a scalar variable declared outside the loop's
>   scope.

Comment: useful but i already get 0 instead of 3, i dont understand the reason

Comment: With your modified code (setting `open_bound = 0`) I get `0` as the answer without the extra break and `3` when I add my suggested code line.

Comment: i always obtain 0

Comment: @MadiopLO Maybe you have UB as you don't initialize `result_checkin`?

Comment: i think it was the online cpp.sh compilator that gives me always bad results. I compiled with others onlines compilators and it is ok, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use it in my omp loop /:) (OpenMP)

Comment: @MadiopLO See note on loop parallelization in my edited answer. But now, I guess, you'll want to parallelize the ***inner*** loop!?!!

Comment: of course its a global variable in my calculation code, just i think parallelization dont support break command